# Johansen procedure shows cointegration r=1, but ect is not significant?

Tags: regression, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I have 6 variables, all of them I(1). I tested for cointegration and got a significant result for r=1, so I decided to estimate a VECM. The problem is now that the ECTs of the VECM are not significant. In my opinion, this opposes Granger representation theorem, so should I neglect the result of the Johansen test and continue with a VAR model in first differences? This confuses me.

Comment: Please post your results for a better understanding of the issue. Maybe you're using too many lags. In addition, if r=1, it seems you only have one cointegrated relation from a total of six.